# Pandas - Category variable and group by - is this a bug?

Tags: python, pandas

I came across a strange result while playing around with Pandas and I am not sure why this would work like this. Wondering if it is a bug.

```
cf = pd.DataFrame({'sc': ['b' , 'b', 'c' , 'd'], 'nn': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'mvl':[10, 20, 30, 40]})
df = cf.groupby('sc').mean()
df.loc['b', 'mvl']
```

This gives "15.0" as result.

```
cf1 = cf
cf1['sc'] = cf1['sc'].astype('category', categories=['b', 'c', 'd'], ordered = True)
df1 = cf1.groupby('sc').mean()
df1.loc['b','mvl']
```

This gives as result a Series:

```
sc

b    15.0
Name: mvl, dtype: float64
```

`type(df1.loc['b','mvl'])` -> `pandas.core.series.Series`

`type(df.loc['b','mvl'])` -> `numpy.float64`

Why would declaring the variable as categorical change the output of the loc from a scalar to a Series?

I hope it is not a stupid question. Thanks!

Comment: Running version `0.18.1`, I get `15.0` of `numpy.float64` type returned for both cases.

Comment: I am running 0.18.0, I thought I was running the latest version. Thanks a lot for checking with 0.18.1, I'll update and remove the ugly fix I had to add to make the behaviour consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a pandas bug.  The difference is due to the fact that when you group on a categorical variable, you get a categorical index.  You can see it more simply without any groupby:

```
nocat = pandas.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
cat = nocat.astype('category', categories=['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=True)
xno = pandas.Series([8, 88, 888], index=nocat)
xcat = pandas.Series([8, 88, 888], index=cat)

>>> xno.loc['a']
8
>>> xcat.loc['a']
a    8
dtype: int64
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#indexing-categoricalindex) note that indexing operations on a CategoricalIndex preserve the categorical index.  It appears they even do this if you get only one result, which doesn't exactly contradict the docs but seems like undesirable behavior.

There is [a related pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/12531) that seems to fix this behavior, but it was only recently merged.  It looks like the fix should be in pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: this bug was fixed in 0.18.1 as indicated in the PR

Comment: It potentially contradicts the docs here where it implies a Series should be returned when slicing using `loc`. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics